# Django ulrs регулярное выражение

Tags: url, регулярные-выражения, python, django

Подскажите как добавить в url слово, чтобы оно не шло в параметр
есть такая строчка

```
url(r'^(?P<country>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/(?P<slug>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)\.html$',
    'resorts.views.resort_detail_description', name='resort-detail'),
```

она формирует такого типа адрес ski/switzerland/verbier.html

нужно сдалать чтобы на другую view переходили по такому url ski/switzerland/verbier_options.html
вот эта строчка выкидывает на туже вьюху resorts.views.resort_detail_description

```
url(r'^(?P<country>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/(?P<slug>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)_options\.html$',
    'resorts.views.resort_detail_additional', name='resort-detail-additional'),
```

**UPD**
полный код urls.py
*то что закоментированно, это те url которые раньше были, то есть раньше на странице выдавалась инфа сразу вся, а теперь надо по url'ам разделить.*

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<country>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/change/$', 'resorts.views.change_country',
        name='change-country'),
    url(r'^(?P<country>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/(?P<slug>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/change/$',
        'resorts.views.change_resort', name='change-resort'),

    url(r'^gallery/(?P<country>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/(?P<slug>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/upload/$',
        'resorts.views.upload_photos', name='resort-gallery-upload'),
#    url(r'^gallery/(?P<country>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/(?P<resort>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/$',
#        'resorts.views.gallery', name='resort-gallery'),
    url(r'^gallery/(?P<country>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/$',
        'resorts.views.gallery', name='country-gallery'),
    url(r'^gallery/(?P<country>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/(?P<resort>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/gallery.xml$',
        'resorts.views.gallery', dict(xml=True), 'resort-gallery-xml'),
    url(r'^gallery/(?P<country>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/gallery.xml$',
        'resorts.views.gallery', dict(xml=True), 'country-gallery-xml'),

    url(r'^ajax/regions/(?P<country>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/$', 'resorts.views.get_regions',
        name='ajax-get-regions'),
    url(r'^ajax/resorts/(?P<country>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/$', 'resorts.views.get_resorts',
        name='ajax-get-resorts'),
    url(r'^ajax/resorts/(?P<country>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/(?P<administrative>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/$',
        'resorts.views.get_resorts', name='ajax-get-resorts-region'),
    url(r'^ajax/search/$', 'resorts.views.ajax_search', name='ajax-search'),

    url(r'^(?P<country>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/$', 'resorts.views.resort_list',
        name='resort-list-country'),
    url(r'^(?P<country>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/(?P<administrative>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/$',
        'resorts.views.resort_list', name='resort-list-region'),
#    url(r'^(?P<country>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/(?P<slug>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)\.html$',
#        'resorts.views.resort_detail', name='resort-detail'),
#new view
    url(r'^(?P<country>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/(?P<slug>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)\.html$',
        'resorts.views.resort_detail_description', name='resort-detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<country>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/(?P<slug>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)_options\.html$',
        'resorts.views.resort_detail_additional', name='resort-detail-additional'),
    url(r'^gallery/(?P<country>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/(?P<resort>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/$',
        'resorts.views.resort_detail_gallery', name='resort-gallery'),   
    url(r'^(?P<country>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/(?P<slug>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)_map_slopes\.html$',
        'resorts.views.resort_detail_slopes', name='resort-detail-slopes'),

)
```

**UPD2**
По совету Ilya Pirogov поменял маршруты местами и заработало. Теперь вопрос, а почему?
И вопрос все-равно остался, а **как в urls исключить какую-то фразу, чтобы она не попадала в параметр?**

Comment: Всё вроде правильно, покажите полный код urls.py, начиная от корневого.

Comment: дебаггер идет на первую вьюху =) сейчас выложу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы по двум разным урл можно было обращаться к одной вьюхе, нужно писать 2 url шаблона, указывающих на одну вьюху.

Вот ссылки на обсуждения подтверждающие это:

- [Optional url parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352834/optional-get-parameters-in-django),
- [Необязательный параметр в роутах](http://softwaremaniacs.org/forum/django/33628/).

И ответ таким образом такой: в одном url шаблоне нельзя исключать параметр. Все указанные в урл шаблоне параметры являются обязательными. Для того чтобы обойти это ограничения, пишут 2 или более урл шаблонов с исключением необязательного параметра во втором.

Comment: Хорошо, но вообще не по теме. Меня не параметры интересуют, а регулярное выражение. Как фразу исключить из параметра.

Comment: В таком случае изъясняйтесь более ясно, что вы имеете ввиду под понятием "фраза"? Напишите выше какую строчку вы хотите исключить из урл шаблона?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте маршрут к `resort_detail_additional` переместить перед маршрутом к `resort_detail_description`.

Либо замените первую регулярку на `r'^(?P<country>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/(?P<slug>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)(?<!_options)\.html$'`

Comment: второй вариант не прошел....ковычку пробовал закрыть не помогло
а вот первый прошел.
Но вопрос все-равно остался, а как в urls исключить какую-то фразу, чтобы она не попадала в параметр?

Comment: > как в urls исключить какую-то фразу, чтобы она не попадала в параметр?

Видимо не совсем понял вопрос, какой параметр вы хотите исключить?